# Is it possible to move existing VSTS resources to a new Azure subscription without issue?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-devops

We have a situation where we are in development and experiencing a lot of delay and resistance from the Azure admin which is creating costly delays and impacting deadlines.

I would like to create our own Azure subscription to allow us to fully admin our environment and pipelines as we see fit, without needing to go through the aforementioned resource.  The admin can link our Dev subscription to their corporate AD later.

We already have some projects in VSTS, build scripts, began some CD development.

Obviously on a new subscription we would just recreate the pipelines and resources.  However, since it would be a new AD, how would this impact our ability to still view content and resources in VSTS?

Link the new AD to the projects?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily associate a VSTS instance with a different Azure subscription, no need to recreate anything. This can be done via the [Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/billing/change-azure-subscription?view=vsts). It can still be connected to the same Azure AD.